# Как избежать переноса буллетов списка влево на картинку?

Tags: html, css

Если сразу за плавающей влево картинкой разместить список, то буллеты будут слева от картинки в IE9 и Opera (неправильно), и справа от картинки в Chrome и Firefox (правильно).

Правильно.

[image]

Неправильно.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img style="float: left; padding-right: 25px;" src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6114/98484902.1b/0_7d838_2c2146e_M.jpg">
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В CSS добавьте:

```
ul{list-style: inside;}
```